# Scale background image and foreground image at same ratio in Android

Tags: android, background, image-scaling, foreground, aspect-ratio

I have a centered background image with a pattern that I am showing using an ImageView. I want it to fill the width and height of all the different screen sizes/densities, but maintain its aspect ratio. I think I have that part figured out, but then I have a foreground image (in a ToggleButton) that is smaller and centered and needs to scale at the same rate of the background image. This is important because the button image has graphical elements that need to align perfectly with the background. How do I get it to scale correctly? Here's what I've got so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relmain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/bg_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_img" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_on"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:onClick="toggleLight" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it like this according to my skills

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/bg_desc"
android:background="@drawable/bg_img" />
```

May be it will look as you want.